# Get array slice of str from vector of objects containing str

Tags: arrays, rust, slice

I have a vector of objects/instances (not sure what the rust parlance is) which have a field containing a string slice. I need to create an array slice containing the string slice fields. Below is my attempt. I am trying to get `foo_bars` to be the same as `what_i_want`.

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: &'a str,
}
let foos = vec![Foo { bar: "one" }, Foo { bar: "two" }, Foo { bar: "three" }];
let foo_bars: Vec<str> = foos.into_iter().map(|foo| foo.bar).collect();

let what_i_want = &["one", "two", "three"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `&` in `Vec<&str>`.

Here's a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c236c165648baf48baf4f29fe43d1036) that works.

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: &'a str,
}

fn main() {
    let foos = vec![Foo { bar: "one" }, Foo { bar: "two" }, Foo { bar: "three" }];
    let foo_bars: Vec<&str> = foos.into_iter().map(|foo| foo.bar).collect();

    let what_i_want = &["one", "two", "three"];

    println!("{:?}", foo_bars == what_i_want);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything must have fixed size, `str` mean a range of characters in string, And the size of string slice can be very.

You need to use a pointer `&`. A pointer is fixed size (`usize`). Depend on cpu architecture (32 or 64) bits.

```
let foo_bars: Vec< str> = foos.into_iter().map(|foo| foo.bar).collect();
                  ^ add a `&` here
```

Comment: A reference to `str` is actually double-sized, a pointer to the beginning and a `usize` of length.